# ordered lists and the way they are structured

Tags: php

y'all!  So what I'm trying to do is two parts:  First, it is essential to know that I've created a database on phpMyAdmin with a table called "lists" that has the columns "id", "name", "times", "level", "email", and "number".  (1) I want to be able to call every one of these columns be referring to them by their id.  (2) Then I want to be able to print out an ordered table that is based on my "levels" data (which is a numerical value between 0 and 3, inclusive) in order from lowest to highest value, and this would keep order even if more inputs are put into the database.  The only problem is that my implementation of (1) doesn't seem to work because nothing gets printed out to the table on the website I made.  Here's what I have:

```
// configuration
require("../includes/config.php"); 

for ($num = 0; $num < 255; $num++)
{
    // get info from database
    $rows = query("SELECT id FROM list WHERE id = ?", $num);
}    

if ($rows === false)
{
    apologize("Oops, something went wrong with the database.");
}

// look up list info
$positions = [];
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $positions[] = [
    "name" => $row["name"],
    "times" => $row["times"],
    "level" => $row["level"],
    "email" => $row["email"],
    "number" => $row["number"]
    ];
}  

// render list of people
render("list_form.php", ["positions" => $positions, "title" => "List"]);
```

?>

By the way, "list_form.php" is the html file which contains the table to which the data should be printed, and ideally ordered in terms of the data in "level".

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Times Available</th>
        <th>Level of Play</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<?php 

    foreach ($positions as $position)
    {
        printf("<tr>");
        printf("<td>%s</td>", htmlspecialchars($position["name"]));
        printf("<td>%s</td>", htmlspecialchars($position["times"]));
        printf("<td>%s</td>", htmlspecialchars($position["level"]));
        printf("<td>$%s</td>", htmlspecialchars($position["email"]));
        printf("<td>$%s</td>", htmlspecialchars($position["number"]));
        printf("</tr>");
    }

?>
<center>
    <a href="index.php">Index</a></li>
</center>

</tbody>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
for ($num = 0; $num < 255; $num++)
{
    // get info from database
    $rows = query("SELECT id FROM list WHERE id = ?", $num); // IF YOU DON'T SAVE THIS IN AN ARRAY, YOU COULD NOT HAVE INFOS...
}
```

you can run just a single query in this way:

```
$maxID = 255;
$rows = query("SELECT id FROM list WHERE id < ? ORDER BY level asc", $maxID);
```